# Left menu disappears from screen

Tags: html, css

The problem I'm having is as follows:

This website I'm working on has a left menu, then content.
The menu on the left should be visible at all times.
On my screen this works just fine, but on smaller screens (<=1280pxx720px) the menu will disappear partially.

So what I would like is that either the menu stays there somehow, or some sort of scroll bar appears (just the vertical scroll bar), so you can scroll to the menu.

I hope there's someone out there with an answer!

The link to the website is: 
http://2xthuis.dev.xsbyte.net/mediation/index

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: It's the `margin-left:-200px` that's causing it.

Comment: @BeatAlex and the `margin-left: -20%` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.sidebar-first .region-sidebar-first {
    width: 270px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I guess this is the first part of the solution, but it is not possible to keep some margin from the actual content.

Comment: Add back the float then and put whatever margin you'd like.